# MySQL SELECT WHERE returning empty with long numbers, although they are there

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Alright, so basically the most simple query ever... I've done this a million times...

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM   purchased_items
 WHERE  uid = '$uid'
```

if `$uid == 123` It works fine and returns all data in rows where uid is 123

if `$uid == 351565051447743` It returns empty...

I'm positive `351565051447743` is a possible `uid` in some rows, i literally copied and pasted it into the table.

$uid is a string, and is being passed as a string.

This is something i've done a million times, and i've never had this simple query not work.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: In PHP, is this a 32 bit server? Is the type of `$uid` an int or string? Even though the value is stored as a BIGINT, if PHP is running on a 32 bit server you can't exceed 4,294,967,295 unsigned.

Comment: $uid is a being passed as a string. I updated the original post with '$uid' in little quotes because thats how it actually is in the php class.

Comment: @brybam but what is `gettype($uid)` before you cast it to a string?

Comment: @and if you `echo $uid` before executing the query, do you see your intended value?

Comment: gettype($uid) says it's a double. But like when I did the 123, I submit it like `WHERE uid = '$uid'` with the small quotes. Do i need to do something different to make it a string if it's a longer number?

Comment: Try removing the quotes. They shouldn't be there anyway, because they force MySQL to convert the datatype. (I'm assuming uid is a numeric field.)

Comment: Is uid a varchar type? If not then try changing it to `varchar(20)`.

Comment: Doesn't work even without the quotes.

Comment: Yes, and I tried that, still same results as before. 123 works, 351565051447743 does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so if you use AMFPHP apparently when you use the browser for testing it doesn't matter if you 'cast' the value as a string in the query. You need to pass it with quotes in the string in the browser interface.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an E{some_power} representation as a string from the double.

What I mean is

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM   purchased_items WHERE  uid = '$uid'";
```

Produces:

```
SELECT * FROM purchased_items WHERE uid = '3.5156505144774E+14'
```

One way to fix it is:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM purchased_items WHERE uid = '%d'", $uid);
```

Not sure if sql supports E format so this may or may not be the issue.
http://viper-7.com/v6MhVe

dit: Quick workaround

```
$format = (is_numeric($uid)) ? '%d' : '%s';
$query2 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM purchased_items WHERE  uid = '{$format}'", $uid);;
```

Comment: How could this still happen even though i'm passing it as a string? There is a chance the UID could have characters in it. So I can't really use a solution that always assumes its a number

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure. Check your generated query to see if this is actually the issue for this particular id.

Comment: How are you retrieving the value. Why is it a double to begin with.

Comment: Well this is an AIR/AS3 project. I'm using AMFPHP to communicate with a php class I have sitting on the web. So, on the flash side, it looks like `gw.call("TestClass.checkUserProducts",responder, uid);` (and uid is a string on AS3 end) then in my php class, just passing it and referencing it list you see above. What's interesting though is if i to getType before i do anything to it, it looks like AS3 is sending it as a double.

Comment: Well I'd see if you can just pass it as a string, not familar with what AMFPHP is, anyways, look at my edit for a workaround

Comment: ugh, wow. sorry for wasting your time. AMFPHP has a browser interface that I use for testing. apparently to technically pass it as a string in the browser interface you have to do "351565051447743" rather than 351565051447743. I didn't think it would matter because it was it small quotes in the mysql query. But once I tested all this in my AS3 app it passed it as a sring and worked. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of `uid` on your table? How about casting `uid` to another datatype?

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM   purchased_items
 WHERE  CAST(uid AS VARCHAR(25)) = '$uid'
```